# Search path for Pyramid modules

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons

I have a Pyramid app, I split models AND views into separate files in following manner:

[How do I split models.py into different files for different models in Pyramid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345698/how-do-i-split-models-py-into-different-files-for-different-models-in-pyramid)

One small consequence for views is that since I have them in separate view files in a "views" package is that they cannot find `models.py`, now `models` package, since it resides in parent directory.

That is, it used to be:

```
models.py
views.py
```

Now it's:

```
views/__init__.py
views/view1.py
views/view2.py

models/__init__.py
models/model1.py
models/model2.py
```

Therefore, importing from `models` in a view results in:

```
    from models import (
ImportError: No module named models
```

Now, I can work around this by adding following path search module extension in `views/__init__.py`:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

But that's kind of kludgy. Is there a better, maybe Pyramid-specific solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really pyramid specific, it is just python.

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages
for a detailed explanation.

You want to

import models.model1

Or

from models.model2 import (...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but it can help some other person.

For solve this, you need to specify your project name. In your case, if the project name is `projet_name` import your models like this.

```
from project_name.models.model1 import *
or
import project_name.models.model1
```

I suppose is not the best way, but it work fine for me.